# Word 2010 Autofit options are missing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

According to the following image (found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/set-text-direction-and-position-in-a-shape-or-text-box-HA010355853.aspx)) I should have 3 options for Autofit within Word 2010.

[image: Support Word Screenshot]

However you can see from my screenshot that I don't. Does anyone know how to enable these extra options? I'm using a standard install of Office Professional Plus 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked to says it applies to Word, Excel and PowerPoint.  However, the picture they used (the one you included) was from PowerPoint.  When I checked my Office 2010 Pro installation, I had three different windows for each of the programs, and only the PowerPoint one matched the picture you included.  I think that you're stuck with the options presented in that window only.

---

[image: Excel 2010 Screen]
[image: Word 2010 Screen]
[image: PowerPoint 2010 Screen]

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that @techturtle. Now to find out if I can make a mail merge in PowerPoint...